# Ontology validator

Tags: web-apps, validation, rdf

I'm currently doing a research on developing a web-based ontology editor.

I need to validate that the ontology edited by my tool is consistent and infer knowledge properly. Also, I would like to get some general statistics regarding the ontology.

Is there an ontology validator tool available online which I can use for this requirement?

[OWL 2 Validator](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/validator) and [OWL Metrics](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/metrics) don't seem to be working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The OOPS! ([OntOlogy Pitfall Scanner!](https://oops.linkeddata.es/)) helps detect common pitfalls for ontology development. There is also a [REST endpoint](https://oops.linkeddata.es/webservice.html) available.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing a summary or screenshot